# About collect (supplier, accumulator, combiner)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I do not understand the utility of the third parameter of the following method:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

from [javaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

> > This produces a result equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  R result = supplier.get();
>  for (T element : this stream)
>      accumulator.accept(result, element);
>  return result;
> ```

as you can see the parameter `combiner` is not used. For example, the following will accumulate strings into an ArrayList:

```
 List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,
                                            ArrayList::addAll);
```

but I expected this:

```
List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add );
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `combiner` is used when your `Stream` is parallel, since in that case several threads collect elements of the `Stream` into sub-lists of the final output `ArrayList`, and these sub-lists have to be combined to produce the final `ArrayList`.

Comment: If parallelly processed, then the original stream order won't be guaranteed in the result after combining. Right?

Comment: @Chen I believe that depends on the combiner passed to `collect`. The combiner can keep the original order.

Comment: @Chen You are right. Order wont be guaranteed. The assumption for the combiner is, combiner operation should be associative e.g. a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c