# How to collect a stream to a list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am following some tutorials on `Java Streams` and it looks like all these Tutorials are already outdated (or obviously I don't get it)

```
 var list = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})
            .filter(x -> x > 3)
            .collect(toList());
```

It tells me this error:

```
Expected 3 arguments but found 1
```

But every tutorial is using exactly a collect code like this.

What is going wrong?

Comment: which version of java do you use for compilation?

Comment: A little bit of debugging could have helped you, but as you said you are from c# background, so fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})` creates an `IntStream`, which doesn't have a `collect` method taking a single parameter (`collect` method of `IntStream` has the signature - `<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator, BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)`). Even if it did, `toList()` wouldn't be applicable, since Java doesn't allow `List<int>` (i.e. `List`s with primitive elements). The elements of a `List` must be of reference type.

You can work with the wrapper `Integer` type instead:

```
var list = Arrays.stream(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})
        .filter(x -> x > 3)
        .collect(toList());
```

Or keep working with an `IntStream`, and box it to a `Stream<Integer>` later in order to collect the elements to a `List<Integer>`:

```
var list = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})
                 .filter(x -> x > 3)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(toList());
```

If you wish to to keep working with `int`s, you can produce an `int` array from the elements of the filtered `IntStream`:

```
var array = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})
                  .filter(x -> x > 3)
                  .toArray();
```

Comment: Can you talk a little bit about the difference between new Integer[] and new int[] ? I am coming from a C# world and i dont understand why this works now

Comment: @Loading I corrected and expanded my answer. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: I deleted my answer, coz you posted way more quicker.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})` will return an `IntStream`, not a normal `Stream<Integer>`.

You could convert it to a `Stream<Integer>` with `.boxed()`:

```
 var list = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6})
            .filter(x -> x > 3)
            .boxed()
            .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:
[About collect (supplier, accumulator, combiner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533316/about-collect-supplier-accumulator-combiner)

and this will solve your problem:

```
ArrayList<Object> collect = Arrays.stream(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }).filter(x -> x > 3)
                .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

*collect here takes three params Supplier,BiConsumer,BiConsumer*
You were giving only one that's why the exception.
Hope it helps:)

Comment: This collect has parameters `Supplier, ObjIntConsumer, BiConsumer`.